# Javascript range.collapse(false) position falling into following paragraph sometimes

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to work out how to manage the problem of double-clicking on a paragraph giving one type of range, vs selected the same paragraph giving a smaller range.

The issue being that if I double-click then the end container seems to be the following paragraph, but when selecting manually then the end container remains the same paragraph.

To demonstrate this I have a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/uagt0z28/39/ that uses insertText to inject text at a range collapse position;

```
var range0 = range.cloneRange();

range.collapse(true);
document.execCommand('insertText', false, '!!!START!!!');

sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range0);
range0.collapse(false);
document.execCommand('insertText', false, '!!!END!!!');
```

the problem is found when you double-click on a word in a paragraph (which selects the whole paragraph), and then you click [setRangeText] to see where the code believes the start and end points of that selection are).
[image: double-click to select whole paragraph]

What I want is that the paragraph is surrounded by the START and END markers to the left and right of the first and last words as seen here ...

[image: manual selection test]

... but what I get is the END marker sitting with the next paragraph (and inside the < p> tag for that para), as seen here...

[image: Double-click test]

How do I fix/correct for this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, JS uses the ending whitespace when making text selections

Comment: For example, triple-click any of your text and paste it in your console... Mine added the ending whitespace